# files changes when merge branch to master

Tags: git

Assume this situation:

1. Create a new branch:

   $ git checkout -b new_branch
2. Change file1 and file2.
3. Add file1:

   $ git add file1
4. Commit:

   $ git commit -m "changed file1"
5. Merge the new branch with master:

   $ git checkout master

   $ git merge new_branch

What happen with file2. Will be changed in master branch? Or only added and commited changes are changed in master branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If file2 is not added to git, then it will not change on branch changes. Git only tracks files that you add to it.

Comment: All right, so if I want to discard all changes that I've not added, Do I have to do "$ git checkout -- *"?

Comment: No, a simple `git clean -dxf` will remove all files that are ignored or not tracked. `git checkout -- *` will only update tracked files to their committed state.